# Why Encoding.ASCII != ASCIIEncoding.Default in C#?

Tags: c#, encoding, character-encoding

Why does Encoding.ASCII != ASCIIEncoding.Default in C#?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is because `ASCIIEncoding` derives from `Encoding`, where `Default` is defined as:

```
/// <summary>  
/// Gets an encoding for the operating  
/// system's current ANSI code page.  
/// </summary>  
public static System.Text.Encoding Default
{ get; }
```

So `ASCIIEndcoding.Default` actually returns operating system’s default ANSI encoding.

Comment: So you're actually calling Encoding.Default, there is no ASCIIEncoding.Default. Resharper (and maybe FxCop) will warn you about that.

Comment: Just to clarify further: The `Default` property is a static property that is always inherited from the `Encoding` class, no matter what encoding class you call it from.